# Rendering a form that creates an object that is Nested under two other models.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-resources

I'm building a rails app that has a an object that is created /nested underneath two objects.

Routes.rb

```
resources :pages do
     resources :referralpages do
      resources :rewards do
      end
     end
  end
```

I've just added the rewards resource and have this for my form for creating a new reward

```
<%= form_for ([@referralpage, @reward]) do |f| %>
  <% if @reward.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@reward.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this reward from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @reward.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :level %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :level, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :dscount %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :discount, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I need help getting the form_for ([@referralpage, @reward]) portion working.

Here's the error message I'm getting when clicking the new reward button:

```
undefined method `referralpage_rewards_path'
<%= form_for ([@referralpage, @reward]) do |f| %>
```

my guess is that it's routing to the incorrect path. What's the proper syntax to get this to work?

I think it should render this path

```
 new_page_referralpage_reward
```

The point of this feature is to render rewards in the referral/show.html.erb page

I have created an index partial in my rewards view file and am rendering it in the show action of the referralpages/show.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot put more than one resource path in **form_for** which cause invalid path.

Why you want to put 2 resource path in form?
Do you plan to save the same data for referral & rewards Model?
If, yes use just one path and make a create method in your controller to save to other model.

From this point of view:

> The point of this feature is to render rewards in the
>   referral/show.html.erb page

If you only plan to render the data of **rewards** to **referral/show.html.erb**,

in your **referral controller**

```
def show
   @rewards = Reward.all #example
end
```

Unless, you have model relationships like:

```
#Reward Model
belongs_to :refferal

#Referral Model
has_many :rewards or has_one :reward
```

With model **realtionship**:

```
def show
  @referal = Referral.all #example
end
```

**show.html.erb** View # iterate it:

```
<%for referral in @referral%>
  <% referral.rewards %> # need to iterate if has many
  or
  <%= referral.reward... %>
<%end%>
```